# How to convert 9 digit number into a particular date format?

Tags: date, datetime, numbers

I want to convert 9 digit number into a particular date format.

**Example -**

> Number - 000007547 ===> Date - 2016/10/05
>
> Number - 000007550 ===> Date - 2016/10/08
>
> Number - 000007559 ===> Date - 2016/10/17

I already have this numbers and it's dates but I'm unable to find the logic behind that conversion. Is anyone aware of this 9 digit date-time format?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the number is a count of days.

Try this python script:

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(1996, 2, 6)
d1 = date(2016, 10, 17)
delta = d1 - d0
print delta.days
```

To convert this format you can use this script:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

d0 = date(1996, 2, 6)
d1 = date(2016, 10, 17)
delta = d0 + timedelta(days=7559)
print delta
```

Output: 2016-10-17

Answer (score 0):

It is the timestamp.

A timestamp is encoded information, which indicates the date and time at which a particular event has occurred.

```py
import datetime

value=1258094605
date_obj=datetime.date.fromtimestamp(value)
print(date_obj)
```